# Multi users chat, compare users on conversation - MYSQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a sort of chat with multiples users, I have 3 different tables `conversations` and `conversations_users`, `messages`

**Conversation table:**

```
id | founder_id | created_time
```

**Conversations users table:**

```
id | user_id | conversation_id
```

**Messages Table**

```
id | conversation_id | user_id | message
```

lets say that on the conversation with ID 1 there are 3 people to chat and the chat with ID 2, 2 people as well

```
 user_id | conversation_id
    1              1
    2              1
    4              1
    3              2
    4              2
```

But the problem is that I want check if the conversation between users `1,2,3,4` exist before do any action and direct the message on the right conversation.

but obviously the conversation with the users `1,2,3,4` will be totally different for the conversation with the users `3,4`

Witch is the logic for compare exactly that users to the table `conversations_users` and get the uniqueness of that conversation?

**Edit:**
It work similar to the chat of facebook, where I can start a conversation with 3 or 4 different people or just with 2 or whatever, there is no "rooms" already setted, the user will create a conversation once he send the first message, for this reason I need to check if that user has already an conversation with the others uses without have the conversation ID

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `conversation_users` at all. Just have `conversations` and `conversation_messages` that stores the message, the user who posted it and the conversation it was posted to.

Comment: mmmh interesting, and how do you check if the conversation exist having only the id of users?

Comment: Why do you need to? Surely users can create any combination of conversation they want?

Comment: Yes but you asking me why I want to check if the conversation exists between two or more users? are you ok? Do you think is a bad idea check if the conversation exists for prevent that same user change only the input and that's it he belongs to another conversation without permission?. If you think another way just let me know :)

Comment: It depends on how you're creating conversations, how you're displaying them to the user. If you're displaying it as a chat room and submit the message in a chat room style, then you submit the conversation ID with the message, it doesn't matter who is in the room.

Comment: That's right, but unfortunately it work similar to the chat of facebook, where I can start a conversation with 3 or 4 different people or just with 2 or whatever, there is no "rooms" already setted, the user will create a conversation once he send the first message, for this reason I need to check if that user has already an conversation with the others uses without have the conversation ID. I really appreciated you view point look forward if we can achieve the result. :)

Comment: @Styphon you have to know who is in the room so that you know who to display the room to, unless all rooms are public and anyone can join any room.

Comment: Exactly Kevin, can you help about that?